# Apache.conf not sending http headers

Tags: php, apache, http

I'm trying to get http headers sent for my website using the apache.conf files, but nothing seems to be working. I have this at the bottom of my apache.conf files:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set X-Frame-Options: deny
Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Header set X-WebKit-CSP: "default-src 'self'"
Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: "master-only"
</IfModule>
```

I enabled headers, and restarted apache, and then checked my pages and it isn't sending any of these headers. Am I missing something simple here? I've even tried doing this in the php pages with header() function and it still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.